# Android/iOS Apps Crashing, do they need deletion for new update to occur?

Tags: android, ios, updates

I've got a development partner who says that in order to fix bugs that cause an application on iOS & Android to crash on load that end users need to delete the original app and re-download the new updated version. Are they for real? Shouldn't it just be incorporated into a standard app update and work like any other update?

Comment: You need a new development partner. Forcing a user to delete and reinstall an app (resulting in lost data) to workaround bugs made by the developer is just silly. Fix the app to properly handle the update scenario.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. It's actually a client's dev partner that I'm trouble shooting this for. Do you have any threads/articles that would disprove the need to uninstall/re-install, because ya, that's crazy.

Comment: I don't know of an article. Simply point out to the client how crazy this is and that there's no technical reason why the app can't properly handle an update if written properly.

Comment: Thanks so much, very much appreciate the POV.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how your app was distributed.  If you just sent out a link like http://www.mysite.com/mytestApp.apk, it's easiest to uninstall.  If they're updating via the Google Play Store, you have to set your version number higher than the installed version.  Users can then get the newer version more seamlessly.  I haven't done an ad hoc distribution with iOS yet, but updates via the app store seem to work similarly to the Play store.  Users get a notification and can then update if their device meets the required specs.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Ideally, the updates for users would occur via a Play or App Store update pushed to their device...from what you're saying it's as simple as making the changes, updating the version number and pushing them out via the store(s)?

Comment: Yes, the stores are pretty sophisticated for distribution.  Your users shouldn't need to uninstall unless the developer has done something wrong like losing their Signing certificate so they can't rebuild the binary or changing the app name. You can even transfer the app to another Apple developer account and still keep the download and version history.  One note, though: updates through the Apple App store would take an extra week or two while they review the new binary.  I always spend (what feels like) unnecessary time packaging my apps, so I'd say "simple" is not quite the word.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually an update should resolve these issues. However, I have seen rare instances where users running older apps will need to uninstall/reinstall to get the new version of the application working. Like I said, these are rare instances where some major configuration has to take place. It's not something most updates need to do.

Comment: The app launched roughly fall 2013 so it's pretty new. I'm just trying to find some proof points against the logic (or lack there of) that states the end user needs to delete/reinstall. I suppose its tough without really knowing the fine details on the cause for crashing.

Comment: You are approaching this from the wrong end.  Since there is **never** a need to uninstall and reinstall, then you should be asking them for proof points, not vice-versa.  They have asked you to prove the true == false.

Comment: Thanks Simon, completely agree. I think I've got some good reputable POVs here to question the developers capabilities. Thanks!